AWS Lambda successfully calls Secret Manager but returns "Missing Authentication Token" instead of secret
I have a .NET 8 AWS Lambda function hosted behind an API Gateway and on a VPC.  As a part of the function's workflow, it retrieves a secret from Secrets Manager inside the same AWS account.
The Lambda successfully calls Secrets Manager via the following call:
var secretResp = await client.GetSecretValueAsync(new GetSecretValueRequest { SecretId = secretId });
However, the SecretString property of secretResp reads "Missing Authentication Token" (instead of the actual secret).
Note that I only get this error when the Lambda is executed as deployed in AWS.  It works fine if I run it locally in Visual Studio with AWS Explorer connected to my AWS account.
Here's what I have tried:

In API Gateway -> Resources -> Integration Request -> Method Request, I have set Authorization = NONE, API key required = False, and Request Validator = None.
I attached the policy SecretsManagerReadWrite (which includes the action secretsmanager:*) to my Lambda function's execution role.

Yet I still get the "Missing Authentication Token" message  What am I missing?

The issue ended up being the credentials that I was passing to the AmazonSecretsManagerClient constructor.
I had forgotten that when running locally I was using my local config/credentials files under <user_profile_folder>\.aws.
